# ASP.NET DataGrid Dropdown Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET DataGrid and one of it's columns(Services) is a label and in Edit mode it is a dropdownlist"

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <ASP:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceName") %>'    runat="server" ID="lbSName" />
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
  <ASP:DropDownList id="ddlServices" AutoPostBack="False" cssClass="DropDownList"   runat="server" datasource="<%# dvAllServices  %>" DataTextField= "ServiceName" EnableViewState="True" DataValueField="ID" OnPreRender="SetDefaultListItem" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Please see the picture:

[image]

As you see Dropdown is bound to dvAllServices which is populated in the Page_Load Event.

The issue is everytime I click on Edit button this dropdownlist gets populated and shows the topmost item. I want to show whatever it was showing before the Edit.

I know how to set the Dropdown index using the selectedIndex and find methods. But I'm not sure "Where" should I do this in the above scenario. I tried to set it in the Grid "Edit"Event but, Dropdown has value of `nothing` in that event.

Any feedback is appreciated,

Comment: You'll need to add an ondatabound event for the grid, and set the dropdown selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will work

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && 
        (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    { 
        // Here you will get the Control you need like:
        DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dvAllServices ");
    }
}
```

Comment: ddlServices in this event still has value of nothing.
note that I popuatae this dropdown on the page load event.

Comment: OK My Bad, I was not checking to see if current index is >1

Answer (score 0):

I will accept Bibhu's answer as it gave me enough guidelines.

But Since I am using "DataGrid" and not GridView which does not have a RowDataBoundevent , I add this code for the future reference in case a user uses DataGrid Control:

```
 Protected Sub grdServices_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs)

    Dim ddlrowServices As DropDownList = e.Item.Cells(2).Controls(1)

    Dim iOriginalServiceIndex As Integer = CInt(ViewState("locationOfOriginalService"))
    ddlrowServices.SelectedIndex = iOriginalServiceIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: Curious ... what framework version are you on? 
EditCommand would be usable too.  Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: The answer to this question was ondatabound event as you mentioned in your first comment. If wonder why you did not put that as an answer :)

Comment: I'd did, but i was editing it because of some misspellings. Edit time ran out, so I deleted it ... and didn't get it recreated in time ... o well :-)